# How to use Ringtone picker from within any "not Activity" (without Activity)

Tags: android

Is there a way to use ringtone picker without Activity?
That is from DialogPreference in my case.

As DialogPreference is not Activity, there are two problems here:

1. There is no startActivityForResult
2. There is no onActivityResult method.

I managed to use startActivityForResult by casting Context received in contructor to Activity, but I can't find way to catch any results.

As a workaround I created custom AlertDialog with singleChoiceItems set using ringtones' Cursor from RingtoneManager, but that doesn't include "default ringtone", selected ringtone, doesn't play music and just "feels different" from default ringtone picker.

To sum up - is there any way to run Ringtone picker from DialogPreference or do I need to create whole custom Dialog?

EDIT:
That is custom Ringtone picker solution I came up with (question still stands - how to use default Ringtone picker instead?). It has some drawbacks (especially temp path - how to fix it?), but may be useful to someone

```
// all this is inside some Dialog or other non Activity
Context mContext;
    // that is the string I want to get from Ringtone picker
    // something like  content://media/internal/audio/media/60
    // I can also get it stored version from somewhere else (preferences and such)
private String mRingtonePath = null; 

    // that is temp path I am using, because I can't find other way to store path 
    // received in setSingleChoiceItems onClickListener
private String mRingtoneTempPath = null;

void showRingtoneDialog() {
    RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(mContext);
    final Cursor ringtones = rm.getCursor();
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    int selected = -1;

            // moving to proper ringtone in case some path was already supplied
    if (mRingtonePath != null)
        for (ringtones.moveToFirst(); !ringtones.isAfterLast(); ringtones
                .moveToNext()) {
            selected++;
            String path = ringtones
                    .getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX)
                    + "/"
                    + ringtones.getInt(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
            if (path.equals(mRingtonePath)) {
                break;
            }
        }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("TITLE");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ringtones, selected,
            ringtones.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ringtones.moveToPosition(which);
                    String path = ringtones
                            .getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX)
                            + "/"
                            + ringtones
                                    .getInt(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                    // ugly solution to store temp path
                                            setTempPathTo(path);
                    mp.reset();
                    try {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                        mp.setDataSource(mContext, uri);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();

                            // I could read path nicely from here instead of using temp path,
                            // but ringtones Cursor somehow moves couple positions forward
                            // since last call to onClick in setSingleChoiceItems and 
            // String s = ringtones
            // .getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX)
            // + "/"
            // + ringtones.getInt(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
            mRingtonePath = mRingtoneTempPath;
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

void setTempPathTo(String path) {
    mRingtoneTempPath = path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods you need are parts of Context class. Just pass getApplicationContext to place where it's needed.

Comment: I still need to override onActivityResult method - I don't know how can I do that using getApplicationContext

Comment: You can do it in base activity. Other way - use startActivityForResult() and activity instead of custom dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my problem, but I am aware that I can do that with activities. 
That is not the case however, as I want this DialogPreference to look and act like other DialogPreferences - opening Dialog when chosen, that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RingtonePreference` to get a ringtone and not use a custom dialog.

For example, put this in your preferences

```
<RingtonePreference
      android:key="ringtone"
      android:title="Ringtone Preference"
      android:showDefault="true"
      android:showSilent="true"
      android:summary="Pick a tone, any tone"
    />
```

Reference it by

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String s = prefs.getString("ringtone", "<unset>");
```

I also want to say thank you for your code, I used it for a custom ringtone dialog I needed.